# Articles with proper names

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles, proper-nouns, zero-article

It's correct to use the definite article before the name of a river, canal, sea and ocean:

> - When my father dies, we will have to wash him, wrap him in rich cloth, cremate him, and then sprinkle his ashes into **the Ganges
>     river**.
> - The terminal is located to the north-east of **the Suez Canal**.
> - Land based pollution is relatively high in **the Mediterranean** compared to the other regional seas.
> - Titanic is at the bottom of **the Atlantic ocean**.

However, we don't use an article before a lake:

> - Look, this is **Lake Victoria**.

Why are lakes so special and different from rivers, canals, seas and oceans if it comes to the use of the article?

Comment: Not necessarily because lakes  are anything special, but because the phrase begins with the word *Lake* and not with *Victoria.* "Boats on the Seneca Lake by the castle" ; "After all, this is the GREAT SALT LAKE."  ; " Just past this point is the Avalanche Lake Trail junction."  Compare:"but the main attraction is Lake Tahoma".

Comment: There's no general rule. We say "The Sea of Tranquility".

Comment: @Kris Interesting... So, when we start with "lake", there is no article and when we start with the name, "the" is to be used. I've just thought about the Sea of Japan. "Sea" comes first, so the article should be omitted but it's not... Just an observation.

Comment: @Barmar but "The Sea of Tranquility" is not a geographic name. In addition, it's perfectly logical because of "the+seas" and "of".